# simpleimage.php images disappearing on iphone & ipad

Tags: php, iphone, wordpress, ipad, safari

I'm using simpleimage.php (http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) to create thumbnails on the fly here: http://kera.pounceinc.com/  (please no lectures about the efficiency of doing it this way)

It works great on web browsers including Safari, but on Safari on iphone/ipad the images load and then disappear a second or two later and are replaced with a white box with a border?  I have tried to debug, but can't find a js conflict or media query that is dumping the images.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer...retina.js was in conflict with these dynamically rendered thumbs.